# Retrofit changes numbers even in String format

Tags: android, string, retrofit2

I'm getting list of very long number values with retrofit.
But it seems that retrofit changes them although I define them as String in my model.
here is my model :

```
public class ExchangeFee {

@SerializedName("percent")
@Expose
private String percent;
@SerializedName("amount_usd")
@Expose
private String amountUsd;
@SerializedName("amount_cur")
@Expose
private String amountCur;
@SerializedName("total")
@Expose
private String total;

public String getPercent() {
    return percent;
}

public void setPercent(String percent) {
    this.percent = percent;
}

public String getAmountUsd() {
    return amountUsd;
}

public void setAmountUsd(String amountUsd) {
    this.amountUsd = amountUsd;
}

public String getAmountCur() {
    return amountCur;
}

public void setAmountCur(String amountCur) {
    this.amountCur = amountCur;
}

public String getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(String total) {
    this.total = total;
}

}
```

here is the result when I request by Postman :

```
    "fee": {
        "percent": "5",
        "amount_usd": 5.643299999999999982946974341757595539093017578125,
        "amount_cur": 20.215288720000000211030055652372539043426513671875,
        "total": 107.2226999999999890178514760918915271759033203125
    }
```

and the result that I get from retrofit :

```
5
5.64810000000000034248159863636828958988189697265625
20.112167500000001751914169290103018283843994140625
107.3139000000000038426151149906218051910400390625
```

Seems totally different numbers!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after server response values converted to String type :

```
"fee": {
    "percent": "5",
    "amount_usd": "5.643299999999999982946974341757595539093017578125",
    "amount_cur": "20.215288720000000211030055652372539043426513671875",
    "total": "107.2226999999999890178514760918915271759033203125"
}
```